# Angular Service - Type of object returned is object and not that of the generic type specified

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, rxjs5

I have an angular5 service which does an HTTP get and returns a specific type as shown below

```
public getProductByIDproductId: string): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    const url = `${environment.productservice_baseurl}/${productId}`;
    return this.http
      .get<Product>(url, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(       
        tap(data => (this._product = data)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

The Product class is a class which has properties and methods. A small excerpt is below.

```
class Product{
    productID:string;
    productName:string;

    setQuantity(quantity:number){

    }
}
```

When I call the setQuantity function on this._product returned by the get I get a 'setQuantity is not a function' error. When I try to check the instance of this._product, it is not of type Product but if type Object.

Is the generic type set on the get method only to help compile-time type checking? How do I get a concrete instance of the product class from getProductByIDproductId method?

Comment: You can use a deserializer, like https://kaiu-lab.github.io/serializer/ It handle inheritance and other things

Comment: Thanks. Yes i need to use a serialization library. I am also looking at https://github.com/weichx/cerialize

Comment: Yes Cerialize do the job, unless you need inheritance in your models

Comment: Can you please help understand more. Does cerialize not support inherited types ?

Comment: With cerialize, you have to be explicit about the expected type. It can't handle a case when an object is an Animal, and based on a property it know if its a Cat or a Dog. You have to explicitly ask for a Dog or a Cat, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you're doing.

When you fetch data from an URL, you get just JSON. You're telling TypeScript that `data` is of type `Product`, but that is just a hint for the compiler and does not make it true.

`data` was not created with a call to `new Product` and so it doesn't share its methods.

If you want your `this._product` to behave like a native `Product` instance, you can do this:

```
this._product = data;
Object.setPrototypeOf(this._product, Product.prototype);
```

This way you turn `this._product` into a real `Product` instance, including its methods.

Another option, if you are worried about `setPrototypeOf` and its potential performance drawback, is doing it this way:

```
this._product = new Product();
Object.assign(this._product, data);
```

Of course, this is only a good idea if `Product` has a parameterless constructor. And, in any case, if `data` has properties not defined in `Product` class you can also run into performance issues.

Comment: Oscar, Yes this works but MDN warns against using setPrototypeOf .. see this .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf. I plan to create more services and implement all the HTTP verbs. Would this result in performance issues ?

Comment: Well, for normal cases it shouldn't. I mean, I've done this myself. If you really need that `data` object to act as a Product this is the easiest way. However, I'm editing my post because there is a second way, to do this

Comment: Oscar, Thanks.I am accepting your answer. However, I am still not very sure about how to serialize and deserialize in angular. This represents a gap in my knowledge :-)

Comment: It does not work, at least in Chrome, any of both proposals. Just stays being the interface the service returns.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the response for instance.

```
return this.http
  .get<Product>(url, { headers: headers })
  .map(response => new Product(response)) // I don't know your constructor
  .pipe(       
    tap(data => (this._product = data)),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

This way, you're sure that your object will be a Typescript object that you defined.

**EDIT** You can create an object "by hand" with only a few lines :

```
export class Product {
  // Your class ...

  public static createProductFromHttpResponse = (response: any) => {
    const ret = new Product();
    for (let key in response.key) { ret[key] = response[key]; }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

In your mapping :

```
  .map(response => Product.createProductFromHttpResponse(response))
```

Comment: So, In essence, I will have to hand construct my object and initialize it in the constructor. My object is complex with multiple properties (16 ) , most of them arrays. Thinking more about this , it is basically serialization and deserialization. While your answer will work , is there a more elegant and simpler way to do this ?

Comment: I made an edit to show you a quick way of creating an object from an HTTP response. And I can't think of any other way to do this, because I never faced this issue (I usually don't create functions into my objects)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, to specify response type you should use interfaces instead classes, so your product should be an interface:

```
interface Product{
productID:string;
productName:string;

}
```

And as it is just interface and http response it should not have any methods

**EDIT**

The answer from @trichetriche probably one of the solution for this issue.