# Typescript type safe HTTP post not really type safe

Tags: typescript

SO there is supposed to be a way to call HTTP post and return a typed response by using code like:

```
this.http.post<MyType>(....)
```

I can indeed use the return as it would be `MyType` but it's actually not. It just has the properties but none of my methods defined in `MyType`. Is this a bug and is there a (easy) work around?

Comment: It is not a bug. Methods are not serializable, so it would be impossible to transmit them over HTTP. You'd have to instantiate a new instance of the class and set the properties to those retrieved from the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Service - Type of object returned is object and not that of the generic type specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319020/angular-service-type-of-object-returned-is-object-and-not-that-of-the-generic)

Comment: One way I figure out to have the methods back again in the object is `Object.assign(new MyType(), postResponse)` => you can do it in a `map` operator, for example.

Comment: Sorry, but this IS clearly a bug to me. var dog = new Dog(). dog.bark() returns wuff

Answer (score 3):

Data Transfer Objects (DTO) in JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) cannot contain methods.  DTOs may only contain serializable data.

This is not a bug.

If you want to assign the DTO values to a class instance, use

```
const hydrated = Object.assign(new MyType(), dto):
```